# Placing an object in respect with screen in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiscreen

I would like to set an image view in respect with screen and not the view. I have tried doing something like the following, but it does not work.

```
bgImgView = UIImageView(image: bgImage)
var scrFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
bgImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.origin.y, scrFrame.width, scrFrame.height)
self.view.addSubview(self.bgImgView)
```

Comment: What do you see when you run this code?

Comment: @TomElliott This code works for the most of the time, but once in a while, the photo gets placed  up and goes back to the desired position instantaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the view to the main app window on top of all other views, although this could cause you issues relating to device orientation.

```
bgImgView = UIImageView(image: bgImage)
bgImgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
var scrFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
bgImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrFrame.width, scrFrame.height)
var appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate;
appDelegate.window?.addSubview(self.bgImgView)
```

Depending on what you're intending to do with the image view, you could also create a modal view for this purpose (which I'd recommend over the above).

Comment: Glad to be of help, I'd highly recommend investigating modal view controllers as well though :)